# Recorrer un ArrayList de Items

Tags: java

Buenas,

No consigo recorrer un ArrayList que está formado por Items. Dentro de estos Items guardo diversa información como nombre del juego, fecha de lanzamiento, URL, etc...

Con un bucle foreach puedo entrar a cada Item, pero no consigo sacar información concreta en este punto, por ejemplo el nombre del juego. El ArrayList lo he creado de la siguiente forma:

`ArrayList<Item> games = new ArrayList<Item>();`

Y pretendo recorrerlo de la siguiente:

```
for (Item game: games) {
    //código para acceder a cada campo del Item.
}
```

He buscado información sobre los Items pero no acabo de encontrar nada, quizás se llama de otra forma.

Dentro del Item guardo información para cada juego, por ejemplo:

```
Name: Subnautica (Game Preview)
Type: ---
Descripcion Castellano: Este juego es un trabajo en curso...
Descripcion Pegi:     
Edad Pegi: 16+
Microsoft Store ID: bx3s1q5dvhrd 
Microsoft Store URL: subnautica-game-preview/bx3s1q5dvhrd    
Nota: 4.0    
Pertenece a: -
Tipología de juego: Juego,
```

Comment: Tu código debería mostrar el contenido de manera correcta. ¿Puedes incluir el código completo para buscar el error? ¿Cómo cargas la lista games)

Comment: Usted dice -> He buscado información sobre los Items pero no acabo de encontrar nada, Item es una clase que usted a creado o viene con alguna libreria, motor grafico ect. de ser lo ultimo puede especificar cual. de ser la  segunda en la respuesta de Andoni Alda, comenta lo de los getters, y cnbandicoot comenta lo de "add", si tiene dudas sobre lo que es metodo accesesor, puede hacer una pausa y buscar informacion sobre esto. -> aqui mas resumido https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q-kkcudIIVs o aqui https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7ALMZymOs_s es mas largo pero creo vale la pena. Saludos

Comment: *Me está resultando difícil de comprender el cómo acceder a la información...* seguro que despues de ver los videos lo entiende mejor. Saludos

Answer (score 2):

Una manera muy común de recorrer `ArrayList` es el `Iterator`:

```
Iterator<Item> it = lista.iterator();
// mientras al iterador queda proximo juego
while(it.hasNext()){
    Item item=it.next();
    System.out.println(item.toString());
    System.out.println("tipo: " + item.tipo);
}
```

con un `Item` por ejemplo:

```
public class Item{
    public String nombre;
    public int type; // asumo codigo tres digitos?
    public String descCastellano;
    ...

    @Override
    public String toString(){
         return String.format("%s: %s", nombre, descCastellano);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Lo primero seria crear los **geters** adecuados para tu *item*, por ejemplo para el nombre del juego en la clase **Juego** deberias tener un metodo como este.

```
public String getNombre(){
 return this.nombre
}
```

Entendiendo que en la clase juego tienes un atributo nombre de tipo string. Despues de eso solo tienes que acceder al metodo desde el bucle.

```
for (Juego game: games) {
    System.out.println(game.getNombre());
}
```

Por otra parte debes introducir en el ArrayList objetos (es algo evidente pero como no has puesto esa parte del codigo lo pongo por si acaso)
Esto se hace con el metodo `add()`.

Para ello creas el objeto y luego lo añades, para que puedas ver como funciona puedes hacer esto por ejemplo:

```
Juego j;

    for (i = 0; i<10; i++){
      j = new Juego();
      games.add(j);
    }
```

Te añadira 10 juegos a la lista, tendras que añadirles el nombre del juego, si lo tienes hecho para que se haga en el constructor seria asi

```
Juego j;

    for (i = 0; i<10; i++){
      j = new Juego("Juego "+i);
      games.add(j);
    }
```

Si lo tienes hecho para poder cambiar el nombre con un **setter** seria asi:

```
Juego j;

    for (i = 0; i<10; i++){
      j = new Juego();
      j.setNombre("Juego "+i);
      games.add(j);
    }
```

El setter iria en la clase juego y tendria esta forma:

```
public void setNombre (String nombre){
this.nombre = nombre;
}
```

Comment: Tengo una clase creada para añadir la información a los Items, para el campo "pertenece" lo hago así por ejemplo `item.getValues().put(Constants.PERTENECE, pertenece_a);`. Una vez construido el Item lo agrego a un ArrayList `All_game_list.add(item); `. Me está resultando difícil de comprender el cómo acceder a la información que hay dentro de cada Item. Para el nombre comentas que debería hacer un getter como el que has facilitado, pero por ejemplo para sacar la descripción, ¿tengo que hacer lo mismo? No acabo de ver cómo tendría que hacerlo.

Comment: Si, cuando creas un objeto, le añades atributos de un tipo como puede ser el nombre que es de tipo string, para el resto de atributos (que por lo que veo son todos tipo string) deberias hacer lo mismo. Crear en la clase juego un metodo para recoger (el get) o para introducir (el set) un atributo

Comment: Creo que la Clase Item de @JetLagFox debe contener un `Map` al que accede por el método `getValues()` por la forma que añade los valores. Para tener acceso a esos valores sería tan fácil como pedir el valor de la clave que has cargado (cada constante de `Constants`). Ejemplo: `game.getValues().get(Constants.PERTENECE)`

Comment: Si por lo que parece, no a creado una clase con distintos atributos sino que ha creado una clase con un unico atributo que dentro contiene todo

Comment: @Awes0meM4n Thanks a lot! Solved with your answer. That way I can enter to each item inside. If you want create a response so I can vote up.

Comment: @JetLagFox ya lo puse como respuesta para que puedas aceptarla. Por otra parte recuerda que estás en [es.so] y que se debe usar el español en todas las publicaciones.

Answer (score 0):

Los `ArrayList` se crean con el nombre de la clase que almacena lo que quieres recoger. Lo más normal sería que tu clase que almacena los juegos se llamara `Juego`, y podría construirse de la siguiente manera:

```
public class Juego{
    String titulo;

    //Constructor
    public Juego(String titulo)
    {
        this.titulo = titulo;
    }

    public String getTitulo()
    {
        return titulo;
    }
}
```

Tu `ArrayList` tendría la siguiente forma:

```
ArrayList<Juego> juegos = new ArrayList<Juego>();
```

Para una prueba puedes hacer:

```
Juego juego = new Juego("lo que sea");
juegos.add(juego);
```

Si tu objeto que guarda los juegos se llama `Juegos` como he comentado antes, debes llamar al `get` de la propiedad que pretendes recoger, y lo recogerías de una manera tan sencillo como:

```
for (Juego game: juegos) {
    System.out.println(game.getTitulo());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Por los comentarios que he visto en otras respuestas contando cómo cargas tus atributos veo que cargas un `Map` incluido en tu clase `Item`:

```
item.getValues().put(Constants.PERTENECE, pertenece_a)
```

Para tener acceso a los valores cargados puedes pedirselos a ese `Map` por la clave que hayas usado (cada constante de `Constants`). Un ejemplo dentro de tu `for` sería:

```
game.getValues().get(Constants.PERTENECE)
```

Answer (score 0):

Suponiendo que el codigo de tus Items sea algo asi:

```
public class Item {
private String nombre;
private String genero;

public Item(String nombre, String genero) {
    super();
    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.genero = genero;
}

public String getNombre() {
    return nombre;
}

public void setNombre(String nombre) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
}

public String getGenero() {
    return genero;
}

public void setGenero(String genero) {
    this.genero = genero;
}
```

}

Si tuvieras un ArrayList con estos Items podrias acceder a sus valores a traves del metodo ArrayList.get(index).getAtributo(); de la sigiente manera:

```
//supongamos que tienes un ArrayList de Item llamado items
    
    for(int i = 0;i<items.size();i++) {
        System.out.println(items.get(i).getNombre());
    }
```

Con un bulce for recorremos el ArrayList usando como maximo indice el numero de elementos del ArrayList que lo obtenemos con ArrayList.size(). Luego accedemos a cada item con el metodo ArrayList.get(indice) y finalmente accedemos al atributo con el metodo get correspondiente. Asi podremos, por ejemplo, imprimirlo por pantalla.